# CFNetwork crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, cfnetwork

We have rarely occurring set of crashes (1.5%) appear in considerable quantities and below are screenshots of Crashlytics reports.

I cannot reproduce any of these myself, and none of the app symbols appear in stacktraces. We have UI actions logging implemented, however following users' steps neither helps to understand nor to reproduce the issue.

Heavily used 3rd parties: `AFNetworking`, `SDWebImage`

App is written in `obj-c`

How do I approach tracking down something like this? 

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was `SDWebImage` version `4` cocoapod. After downgrading to `3.8.1` all these crashes disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

One clue is that all of your screenshots of crash stacks indicate that the crash happened as a result of trying to release or free memory. Therefore, it seems possible that your application is incorrectly releasing memory that it does not have ownership of. Maybe a network buffer that you're getting?

My suggestion would be a deep code review, especially of any places where you release memory, to make sure you are using the APIs properly.

Comment: Good catch. I've double-checked, and we don't manually manage memory for networking related tasks or anywhere. We don't have a single malloc or release or free in entire app code (pods excluded). Basically we're using either AFNetworking or SDWebImage for all networking.

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage 4.0 also crash. But 4.1 fix this.